# How do i found total counts from joining tables? it shows wrong count for some columns

Tags: mysql, count

[image]

**I have tried below query but it shows wrong count**

```
 select 
  count(DISTINCT schools.id) as total_schools,
  (select SUM(CASE when schools.is_vts_enabled=true then 1 else 0 END) as vts_enabled from schools where schools.cluster_id = crc_users.id) as vts_enabled,
  SUM(CASE when schools.is_primary=true then 1 else 0 end) as total_primary_schools,
  SUM(CASE when schools.is_secondary=true then 1 else 0 end) as total_secondary_schools,
  COUNT(DISTINCT drivers.id) as total_drivers,
  COUNT(DISTINCT drivers.school_id) as total_schools_with_drivers,
  COUNT(DISTINCT vehicles.id) as total_vehicles,
  COUNT(DISTINCT vehicle_students.vehicle_id) as total_vehicles_with_students
from 
  drc_users 
  left join brc_users on drc_users.id = brc_users.district_id 
  left join crc_users on crc_users.block_id = brc_users.id 
  left join schools on schools.cluster_id = crc_users.id
  left JOIN drivers on drivers.school_id = schools.id
  left join vehicles on vehicles.school_id = schools.id
  left join vehicle_students on vehicle_students.vehicle_id = vehicles.id
 where 
  drc_users.district_id='2401'
  group by drc_users.id
```

I wanted to find total counts from related tables.

```
drc_users->brc_users->crc_users->schools->drivers,vehicles->vehicle_students
```

**I get wrong count in column "total_secondary_schools"**

**Here is sample link** - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed0bf2/3

Comment: Common join multiplying. DISTINCT cannot fix this in a half of cases. So aggregate separate table or minimal joined tableset in the subquery then join the rest of tables or another subqueries.

Comment: Thank you for comment. But can you show some examples related to this?

Comment: Not `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.x) FROM a JOIN b JOIN c` but `SELECT c.cnt FROM a JOIN b JOIN (SELECT COUNT(x) AS cnt FROM c) AS c`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. but it shows the count for all records from table C. I want only related records.

Comment: In the subquery you must select not only COUNT but also all columns which are used for joining and filtering in outer query, and apply needed GROUP BY expression. So you'd obtain not total amount but amounts per needed groups.

Comment: Yes, exactly it will give error if i don't select the field in the subquery that is used for joining the table.but its not working.

Comment: i guess to fix this i need to add join in each left join subqueries, right?

Comment: here it is sqlfiddle link - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed0bf2/3

Answer (score 0):

Be aware:  `JOIN` is performed before `COUNT`.

This syntax is usually what one wants:

```
SELECT
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo )  AS foo_ct,
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bar )  AS bar_ct, ;
```